# Drainage fix: Flat concrete slab up over my vinyl siding by 2 inches. Is this acceptable?

Tags: concrete, drainage, vinyl-siding

I am a new home owner.

The concrete on my front porch sloped towards the house so every time it rained water drained between the porch and the house.

Last week after 8 months the builder took out the concrete and place new concrete. They had to placed it about 2 inches on the vinyl siding.

Is this acceptable?? It is now flat and still does not slope away from the house.

PLEASE ADVISE!

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement.  You can take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 1):

From your question the part that jumps out at me is that you say it is flat.  Also that it is above your vinyl siding.

I recommend first that you examine where it comes into contact with the vinyl and add some clear silicone if there are any gaps.

Secondly, since you say it is flat, I would recommend you go out there with a hose and see how the water flows across it.

You didn't mention if this is catching water from elsewhere or maybe from a roof above, but with the hose you should be able to simulate a rainy condition and then be able to make a determination about whether the fix is going to work for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The concrete slab MUST BE 6” below wood, unless the wood is “treated”.

If that vinyl siding is fastened to a wood wall, the concrete needs to be about 2” below the vinyl, assuming there is a 2x pressure treated sole plate and the vinyl siding is lapping 2” over the concrete wall. (If the vinyl siding isn’t lapping the concrete 2”, then the slab needs to be even lower.)